# Java parse XML for custom tags

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse XML files that have elements that look like this below.

```
<bean id="SPEX"
      parent="SPEXParent">
    <constructor-arg name="delegate">
        <bean id="delegateSPEX"
              parent="delegateSPEXParent"
              p:name="SPEXName)"
              p:maximumClusters="1"
              p:jobFlowRequest-ref="jobFlowRequestSPEX"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="manifestEncryptionManager" ref="manifestEncryptionManager"/>
    <constructor-arg name="emrClient" ref="emrClientFacade"/>
    <constructor-arg name="displayName" value="SPEXDisplayName"/>
    <constructor-arg name="description" value="SPEXDescription"/>
    <constructor-arg name="customerIds">
        <list><ref bean="spex"/></list>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg name="clusterSize" ref="MediumSPEX"/>
</bean>
```

I need to grab the values under "bean id", "bean id" under "constructor-arg name="delegate", "p:name", "p:maximumClusters", "displayName", "description", and "clusterSize". What I have so far is :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(customerFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList poolList = doc.getElementsByTagName("bean");
```

and then I attempt to go through every node in the poolList with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < poolList.getLength(); i++) {
     Node poolNode = poolList.item(i);
     System.out.println(poolNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("clusterSize") 
}
```

but it's never able to find the elements. And I'm not sure how to get the nested "p:name", "p:maximumClusters", etc under the nested bean id. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the name of the attribute "name" and the value "clusterSize"?